# finding running totals using curs

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables Accountmaster and Transactionmaster

accountmaster has columns

ACID
NAME
ADDRESS
CLRbal
Branchid

Transactionmaster has columns

TransNo
DOT
Txntype
Txnamt
ACID
Branchid

Using cursors, I want the running total for clrbal to be printed in a variable whenever a transaction type, cash withdrawl or cash deposit happened.also print an error message when the running total is -ve

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.  What have you tried so far?  What is not working?  Show us your code.

Comment: I agree with @squillman, this sounds like homework especially because of the requirement to use a cursor. There are non-cursor solutions which are more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

i tried something like this.
in the o/p I could get only the first cashdeposit transaction amt as running total

```
create TABLE #v
(
  acid INT , 
  TXNTYPE NCHAR(3), 
  TXNAMT MONEY,
  rt INT,
  --constraint fk_acid foreign key(acid) references accountmaster(acid)
);

INSERT #v(acid, TXNTYPE, TXNAMT) 
  SELECT DISTINCT ACID,TXNTYPE, TXNAMT
  FROM dbo.TRANSACTIONMASTER


DECLARE
 @rt INT, 
 @ACID INT,
 @TXNTYPE NCHAR(3),
 @TXNAMT  MONEY;
SET @rt = 0;

DECLARE c CURSOR 
  FOR SELECT ACID, TXNTYPE,TXNAMT FROM #v 

OPEN c;

FETCH c INTO @ACID, @txntype,@txnamt;

if @TXNTYPE='cd'
BEGIN
  SET @rt = @rt + @TXNAMT;
  UPDATE #v SET rt = @rt WHERE acid = @ACID;
  FETCH c INTO @acid,@txntype, @txnamt;
END
if @TXNTYPE='cw'
BEGIN
  SET @rt = @rt - @TXNAMT;
  UPDATE #v SET rt = @rt WHERE ACID = @ACID;
  FETCH c INTO @acid,@txntype, @txnamt;
END


CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```

Comment: Please edit this into your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First let's put together some sample data. I'm going to add a TXNDATE so that we have something to sort by. For brevity we'll ignore the topic of NULLs, MONEY datatype and alike.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#v') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #v;
CREATE TABLE #v
(
  TXNDATE  DATE, -- something to sort by
  acid     INT , 
  TXNTYPE  NCHAR(3), 
  TXNAMT   MONEY,
  rt       INT
);

--INSERT #v(acid, TXNTYPE, TXNAMT) 
--    SELECT DISTINCT ACID,TXNTYPE, TXNAMT
--    FROM dbo.TRANSACTIONMASTER;

INSERT #v(TXNDATE, acid, TXNTYPE, TXNAMT)
VALUES 
('20170102', 1, 'DBT', 12.01), ('20170104',1, 'CRD', 1155), ('20170112',1,'CRD',23.37),
('20170302',1, 'CRD', 124.2), ('20170303', 1, 'DBT', 819.29), ('20170402',1, 'CRD', 11.12);
```

I don't have access to transactionmaster so I'll just make up some sample data.

```
INSERT #v(TXNDATE, acid, TXNTYPE, TXNAMT)
VALUES 
('20170102', 1, 'DBT', 12.01), ('20170104',1, 'CRD', 1155), ('20170112',1,'CRD',23.37),
('20170302',1, 'CRD', 124.2), ('20170303', 1, 'DBT', 819.29), ('20170402',1, 'CRD', 11.12);
```

Now we have

```
TXNDATE    acid        TXNTYPE TXNAMT                rt
---------- ----------- ------- --------------------- -----------
2017-01-02 1           DBT     12.01                 NULL
2017-01-04 1           CRD     1155.00               NULL
2017-01-12 1           CRD     23.37                 NULL
2017-03-02 1           CRD     124.20                NULL
2017-03-03 1           DBT     819.29                NULL
2017-04-02 1           CRD     11.12                 NULL
```

I'll assume that the running total will be sorted by date. First, however, for performance we really want a clustered index on that date.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cl_v ON #v(TXNDATE);
```

Now I don't know much about cursors except to say that you want to run them with FORWARD_ONLY and READ_ONLY. The way I'd approach this would be...

**1. Quirky Update**

```
DECLARE @runningTotal INT = 0;

UPDATE #v
SET @runningTotal = RT = (@runningTotal + CASE TXNTYPE WHEN 'DBT' THEN -TXNAMT ELSE TXNAMT END)
FROM #v WITH TABLOCKX
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

The execution plan leverages the clustered index and performs quite nicely.

[image]

On my system the cost was around 0.013...

**2. WINDOW Aggreage function, (SUM OVER)**

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, 
     RT_NEW = 
       SUM(CASE TXNTYPE WHEN 'DBT' THEN -TXNAMT ELSE TXNAMT END) OVER (ORDER BY TXNDATE)
   FROM #v
)
UPDATE CTE
SET rt=RT_NEW;
```

The execution plan also good.

[image]

Each produces this result

```
TXNDATE    acid        TXNTYPE TXNAMT                rt
---------- ----------- ------- --------------------- -----------
2017-01-02 1           DBT     12.01                 -12
2017-01-04 1           CRD     1155.00               1143
2017-01-12 1           CRD     23.37                 1166
2017-03-02 1           CRD     124.20                1290
2017-03-03 1           DBT     819.29                471
2017-04-02 1           CRD     11.12                 482
```